# how to get traffic data using api

Tags: python, mapbox, here-api, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

Hi I am working on a project that needs traffic data
I am trying to use APIs like [tomtom](https://developer.tomtom.com/map-display-api/documentation/product-information/introduction) or [HERE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-data-service/dev_guide/topics/concept-realtime-traffic-data.html) but i can't get it to work

All I want is to collect the traffic count (number of cars in each route) and stock it in pandas df

I tried this but it didn't give me traffic count

```
response = requests.get('https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/services/4/incidentDetails/s3/-35.871247%2C140.910645%2C-28.902397%2C153.566895/22/-1/json?key='+apiKey+'&projection=EPSG4326&originalPosition=true')
dict = json.loads(response.content)
print(dict)
keys = dict.keys() 
values = dict.values()
```

I can use any other api instead of tomtom if it can provide data too

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is contained in `response.content`?

Comment: a bytes blob, most likely

Comment: whats the apiKey for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this here code:

```py
from json import dumps as to_json_func_from_the_json_module

from requests import get

key = 'tada!'
response = get(f'https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/services/4/incidentDetails/s3/-35.871247%2C140.910645%2C-28.902397%2C153.566895/22/-1/json?{key=!s}&projection=EPSG4326&originalPosition=true')
dct = response.json()

print(to_json_func_from_the_json_module(dct, indent=2, default=str))
print('N. (#) Keys:', len(dct))
```

It should work. Let me know if not.

Comment: the apikey is key that is provided by tomtom after sing in up it is used to connect to tomtom api
the code does not give any errors it just dosen't provide traffic count 
here is the output 
{'@id': '1682942440',
  'poi': [{'id': '0aab15fcf8096e2691de5f01aa5b06f8',
    'p': {'x': 140.8933447, 'y': -34.2666487},
    'op': {'x': 140.8933443, 'y': -34.2666511},
    'ic': 9,
    'ty': 0,
    'cs': 0,
    'd': 'roadworks',
    'sd': '2023-04-19T08:23:00Z',
    'f': 'Loxton Main Road (Sturt Highway)',
    't': 'West Settlement Road (Sturt Highway)',
    'l': 3788,
    'r': 'A20'},

Answer (score 0):

Those services do not return number of cars.

Answer (score -1):

To get the number of cars (samples) within a route, you can use either [Traffic Stats API](https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-stats/documentation/product-information/introduction) or [O/D Analysis](https://www.tomtom.com/products/origin-destination-matrix-analysis/) from TomTom. but you need a custom payment for it. you can have a free trial for only a month using the [Move portal](https://move.tomtom.com) but it's pretty limited in terms of date range available and number of reports you can make. regarding HERE's, I explored that before and they don't provide the number of cars at all. if someone has a better experience using these services I hope they can add more on this.